# Is this a hat problem? Date seems to be off

Tags: bug, hats

I just got an *Mmmm Bacon* hat which is described as

> ask, answer, or vote on **December 30th**

but it's still **December 29th**??!!

Whom do I need to tell?

Comment: See [Is there something wrong with “Mmmm Bacon” hat mechanism?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288987/340816) on Meta SE. I can only hope you aren't a vegetarian or a vegan :-P

Comment: Actually the answer given does not explain this behavior. It was still the 29th in Auckland(GMT+13), Tokyo(UTC+9), and Shanghai(UTC+8) when I received my hat.

Comment: I pointed to that question because hats are a feature that works across the Stack Exchange network, so Meta SE is the most suitable place to check or ask about it.

Comment: In a nutshell, the hat can be acquired as long as it is December 30 *somewhere* in the world, so the actual window (due to timezone oddities) is slightly over 2 full days.

Answer (score 1):

Now we know why [**Mmmm Bacon hat** is awarded on December 30th](http://www.nationaldaycalendar.com/2016/12/29/december-30-2016-bacon-day-no-interruptions-day-falling-needles-family-fest-day-national-bicarbonate-of-soda-day/)